# Convergence of double sum and its rearrangement

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, double-sequence

Let $A=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij},a_{ij}\geq 0$ and $$\phi:\mathbb N \to\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$$ be any bijection. Now $B=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{\phi(k)}$.

How $A$ and $B$ are related.  My intuition tells both series converges are diverges together and if converges, they converges to same value. But I didn't able to prove this. Please give sketch o the proof.

Also, how the converges of both series related if $a_{ij}$ are not necessarily non negative.

Comment: @Dayton Actually, I realized it is relevant to the question in the last line.

Comment: I deleted the comment, but I will re-post for completeness as it applies to the last line "see Riemann series theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem [when $a_{i,j}$'s can have any sign]".

Comment: Hint: Consider the sets of partial sums of both sides, and prove that they have the same set of upper bounds.

Comment: @Jair Taylor, I will try to work on your hint,

Comment: @Dayton  , my question is specifically about double series

Comment: more specifically, show that any partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^K a_{\phi(k)}$ is bounded by a partial sum $\sum_{i=1}^{M}\sum_{j=1}^{N}a_{ij}$ by choosing $M,N$ large enough so that each $a_{\phi(k))}$ is a summand. And  similarly for the reverse inequality.

Comment: The Riemann series theorem is still applicable. e.g. take $a_{i,j} = (-1)^i (1/i)$ for $j = 1$, otherwise $0$. Then $B$ can evaluate to any real number.

Comment: @Jair Taylor thanks, it helps but you gave entire solution as hint lol.

Comment: @SathasivamK Oops :) Hard to know how much of a hint to give.